# How to pass a view with OnTouchEvent

Tags: android, kotlin

I created some code that implements GestureDetector in conjunction with OnTouchListener:

```
val detector = GestureDetector(object: GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent?) {
                super.onLongPress(e)
            }

            override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                return true
            }
        })

        val gestureListener = View.OnTouchListener(function = { view, event ->
            detector.onTouchEvent(event)

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
               // do something
            }

            false
        })

        profilePic1.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener)
```

When I call

```
detector.onTouchEvent(event)
```

I would like to pass the current view, so the functions inside the detector can handle the relevant view. In this example only the view profilePic1 is passed to the listener, but I would like to add many views to handle. Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please go through the following link and let me know if this helps?

https://github.com/ishtdeephora/SnippetsRepository/blob/SnippetsRepository/app/src/main/java/com/example/ishtdeep/gestureimplementation/MainActivity.kt

Comment: Hello, thank you, what's the difference between that snippet and the code I provided?